# Using Python's datetime module, can I get the year that UTC-11 is currently in?

Tags: python, django, datetime, timezone, utc

I would like to get the year that the UTC-11 timezone (the last timezone to enter the new year) is currently in, but I'm not sure how to do this.

I have access to the `pytz` library, as well as Django's new `timezone` module, and I'm using timezone-aware, UTC datetime objects.

Comment: What's missing from the demo code at [pytz home page](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest would be to skip the timezone processing entirely, and just use `timedelta(hours=11)` to subtract from the `datetime` and look at the `year` attribute.

```
>>> (datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.timedelta(hours=11)).year
2012
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, timezones are a bit trickier than that... You may have timezones with the same offset but with different settings when it comes to power saving dates and such (or even nastier behaviours: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6841479/289011)

I think for this specific case, you may be better off with:

```
>>> "%s" % (datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.timedelta(hours=11))
'2012-12-26 00:25:30.029864'
```

Just for the year:

```
>>> "%s" % (datetime.datetime.utcnow() - datetime.timedelta(hours=11)).year
'2012'
```

Edit:
Yeah, and it's good idea using `datetime.utcnow()`, not `datetime.now()`... (my bad)

Comment: Or - just use `format(some_datetime_like_obj, '%Y')` (relating to your "just for the year")